# Change input value on tab

Tags: javascript, html

I'm coding a small web app to log team members work time. It all works well, except one thing. When you tab on a fieldset a new page opens with a form to change the time for that person. The first time you tab it works, but when you click on the next fieldset it changes all input fields with the name 'begin-time' ?

I think i'm missing something but I'm not sure what it is.

I have the following form;

```
<form id="time-form">
  <fieldset>
    <div class="row">
      <input type="text" value="Jonh Doe" id="fullname" name="fullname" readonly="">
      <div class="time">
        <input type="text" value="00:00" id="begin-time" name="begin-time" readonly="">                     
        <input type="text" value="00:00" id="end-time" name="end-time" readonly="">                     
      </div>
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset>
    <div class="row">
      <input type="text" value="Jane Doe" id="fullname" name="fullname" readonly="">
      <div class="time">
        <input type="text" value="00:00" id="begin-time" name="begin-time" readonly="">                     
        <input type="text" value="00:00" id="end-time" name="end-time" readonly="">                     
      </div>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

with the new form 'on tab';

```
<form id="add-time">
  <input type="time" name="begin_time">
  <input type="time" name="end_time">
</form>
```

and the javascript;

```
$$('#time-form fieldset').tap(function() {  

var beginTime = $(this).find("[name='begin-time']");

$('#add-time input[name=begin_time]').change(function() {
    beginTime.val(this.value);
});

$$('.add-time').tap(function() {
    $('#addTimePage').addClass('pt-page-moveToRightEasing pt-page-ontop');
    $('#timePage').addClass('pt-page-moveFromLeft pt-page-current');

    setTimeout(function () { 
        $('#timePage').removeClass('pt-page-moveFromLeft');
        $('#addTimePage').removeClass('pt-page-moveToRightEasing pt-page-ontop pt-page-current');
    }, 400);
});
});
```

edit: I have setup a simple [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/J4Hjf/1/) of the problem.

Comment: Can you set up a jsfiddle so we can see the problem in action?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so I noticed a few problems:

1. Your first `.click()` call was targeting ALL time-form fieldsets when it should have only been targeting input fields.
2. Your `.change()` and second `.click()` are called inside the first `.click()` meaning the new methods will be called multiple times (because each use of `.click()` and `.change()` adds on to the actual event.
3. Your submit button wasn't actually submitting anything. It was just hiding itself.

To fix this, I gave each fieldset a class name of `.fieldset-time` so they can easily be looped through. I added an `onclick()` event to each `<fieldset`> to easily manipulate the one (and its children) that was clicked.

Here's the new JavaScript code:

```
// invoked each time an input with the onclick() attribute is clicked
function editTime(obj) {
    $("#addTimePage").fadeIn();
    $(obj).attr("id", "active"); // set id to active so we know this is the one we want to change
}

$("#submit").click(function() {
    // get the new beginning and end times set by the user
    var newBeginTime = $("#add-time input[name=begin_time]").val(); 
    var newEndTime = $("#add-time input[name=end_time]").val(); 

    // loop through all elements with class .fieldset-time and find the active one
    $(".fieldset-time").each(function() {
        if ($(this).attr("id") == "active") {
            $(this).attr("id", "");
            $("input[name=begin-time]", this).val(newBeginTime);
            $("input[name=end-time]", this).val(newEndTime);
            return false; // break out of the .each() loop
        }
    });

    // finally, clear and hide the add time box
    $("#add-time input[name=begin_time], #add-time input[name=end_time]").val("");
    $("#addTimePage").fadeOut();
});
```

And the new JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/J4Hjf/7/

I hope that's what you were looking for. :)

Comment: No sorry, I have setup a fiddle with your code but still getting the same result

Comment: Sorry it took so long, but I figured it out! :) I'll update my answer right now.

Comment: This is a nice solution, thnx for that! But after testing this out it is not exactly what I was looking for. Now you have to click on every input field to set the time. What I was looking for is that you click on the fieldset to change the begintime and endtime per member. 

Sorry if I was a little bit vague on that one. I have updated the fiddle to show you what I mean: http://jsfiddle.net/J4Hjf/6/

Comment: Oh I see! Well that's no problem; just a few edits. I'll update my answer now. E: Updated. All I changed was I moved the onclick() to the fieldset elements and added a class to them as well. Then all we had to do was add a couple lines to change the end time and start time simultaneously.